# PHP getallheaders alternative

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I am trying to switch from apache to nginx on my server. The only problem here is the getallheaders() function I used in my PHP scripts which does not work with Nginx. I have tried the user contributed notes on php site on getallheaders finction but that does not return all request headers.

Please tell me how to solve this problem. I would really like to switch to Nginx.

Comment: What headers are you missing? Are you sure the header you are missing really is a request header and not something set by apache?

Comment: I am missing custom headers sent by client for example my app requires ownet-id field which can't be accessed without getallheaders.

Comment: It's available on PHP 5.4 FastCGI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can still use it but you will have to re-define/re-write it like here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#84262

Comment: I have used this method but no luck. It doesnt give me all the headers that I want. For example my app requires client to send "owner-id" header. This is can't get with any function except getallheaders().

Comment: Is the header value sent for each page the same? or different for each page?

Comment: Like someone later posted on the page, make sure you take Content-Type and Content-Length into account, as they don't follow the same naming convention. See this post:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#104307

Answer (score 6):

A request header of Owner-ID will be passed to php as $_SERVER['HTTP_OWNER_ID'] by nginx.  All request headers are passed in a similar manner.

Comment: I just tested by calling a php script containing <?php var_export($_SERVER); ?> using curl -H 'Owner-ID: foobar' and $_SERVER['HTTP_OWNER_ID'] has a value of foobar.  Did you maybe disable this behavior with fastcgi_pass_request_headers off;?

Comment: I have uninstalled nginx... It may be providing headers this way but has many other problems like you cant install module without recompiling the server. This is annoying to deploy on production servers. I would like to remain on apache now until nginx become mature enough. Anyway thanks for the help